# Closed sets as $A\cap B = \varnothing$ such as $\inf \{\|a − b\| \mid a\in A, b\in B\} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis

Let $E$ be a normal vector space, $A$, $B\subset E$ closed, nonempty subsets.

We denote by $c = \inf\{\|a − b\| \mid a\in A, b\in B\}$.

I gotta find $2$ closed sets $A$, $B$ such that $c = 0$ and $A\cap B = \varnothing$.

And then, for these sets, give an example of sequences $\{a_{n}\}$ and $\{b_{n}\}$ such that $\|a_{n} - b_{n}\| \to 0$.

I have the idea of  $A = N - \{0\}$ and $B = \{(n+1)/n \mid n \in\mathbb{N}_{>=2}\}$ for my closed sets.

Is it okay? I'm kinda lost about the sequences

Thank You for your help

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Assuming that $A =  \mathbb N \setminus \{0\}$, $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint since $2 \in A \cap B$.

Comment: Those sets work since $a_n=n$ and $b_n=n+\frac{1}{n}$ so $|a_n-b_n|=\frac{1}{n}\to 0$

Comment: @AndrewShedlock But these sets are not disjoint, as required in third sentence of post.

Comment: The problem is that $B$ is not closed. You won't find example in a Banach space.

Comment: @coffeemath, yes but its at one point so Jazz can make the adjustment

Comment: @AndrewShedlock Yes, all one needs is to start $B$ at $n=2$ [Jazz should have done something like that in stating his example.]

Comment: @AndrewShedlock Yes, I did forget to precise that B start at n=2 ! I'll edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your set $A$ is OK, but $B$ has to be adapted to $\{n + \frac{1}{n} \mid n =2,3,4,,\ldots\}$. The set $B=\{\frac{n+1}{n}\mid n=2,3,4,\ldots\}$ that you wrote is *not* closed, as $1 \in \overline{B}\setminus B$

Then $a_n = n$ and $b_n = n+ \frac{1}{n}$ $(n \ge 2$) have the property that $|a_n - b_n|  = \frac1n \to 0$.

Another similar set can be found in the plane: $A= \{(x,0)\mid x \in \Bbb R\}$ and $ B = \{(x,\frac1x)\mid x \in \Bbb R\setminus \{0\}\}$, where $a_n=(n,0)$ and $b_n = (n,\frac1n)$ have similar properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a solution over $\mathbb{R}^2$: take the function $x\mapsto 0$ and for example $x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}$ because for continuous functions the set ${(x,f(x))}$ is closed and in this case the graphs are disjoint

Comment: you mean the graphs of the two functions $x\mapsto 0$ and $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$, right?

Comment: yes. that what I meant. I'll use your notation